# adding two registration forms django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using `django-registration` app. I've two registration form `A` and `B`. `A` has default registration fields. And in `B` I've added custom fields and a signal. Following signal also execute for both registration form. That's why I added `if form.is_valid()`. and it sucks. I want to execute only when `BForm` is called. Is there any alternative? Can anyone help me to improve this code? thanks

```
class BForm(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm``
    """
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
```

Signal

```
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    form = BForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        .....
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Django's documentation on the topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/#connecting-to-specific-signals), you can simply do this:

```
user_registered.connect(user_created, sender=BForm)
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On submission of both the forms, the signal will be executed. This happens because signal is sent from the `register` view of `django-registration` after a user is registered. So, no matter what form is used, if a user is successfully registered, signal `user_registered` will be executed.

#### Regarding your issue with form.is_valid():

Since you have `required=False` on `phone` field of BForm, even if `phone` is not present in POST data, your `BForm` will be valid and the code in your reciever function `user_created` would be executed.

You can make following changes to `user_created` to make sure that only when BForm is used then execute the reciever function.

```
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    if 'phone' in request.POST:
        .....
        .....
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```